# Trouble calling Biopython SeqUtils six_frame_translations

Tags: python, global, biopython

when executing the following code:

```
from Bio.SeqUtils import six_frame_translations

blah = six_frame_translations("ATCGATCGATCG")
print(blah)
```

I get the following error:

```
File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\Bio\SeqUtils\__init__.py", line 263, in six_frame_translations
    frames[-(i+1)] = reverse(translate(anti[i:], genetic_code))
NameError: global name 'reverse' is not defined
```

I am using Python 3.23, Biopython 1.59

Any suggestions? Thanks,

Charles

Comment: Duplicate question here: http://www.biostars.org/post/show/51976/trouble-calling-biopython-sequtils-six_frame_translations/

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug. Prior to August 11, 2011, the `SeqUtils` module had a function `reverse`. It was deprecated in version 1.54, and [removed in 1.58](https://github.com/biopython/biopython/commit/31783119799a6f73ab8adc75d601862d3729bac7).

From the file [`DEPRECATED`](https://github.com/biopython/biopython/blob/31783119799a6f73ab8adc75d601862d3729bac7/DEPRECATED):

> Function 'reverse' in Bio.SeqUtils was deprecated in Release 1.54, and
>   removed in Release 1.58. Instead just use the string's slice method with
>   a step of minus one.

So, it looks they just failed to make this conversion in `six_frame_translations()`.
You can submit a bug report to the [OBF Redmine](https://redmine.open-bio.org/projects/biopython) site, or patch it yourself and submit a pull request to the [Biopython repository](http://github.com/biopython/biopython) on GitHub.

If you're feeling especially generous, you might consider writing a unit test to automatically detect failures of this function- it'll help future users like yourself. =)

Comment: Fixed now, https://github.com/biopython/biopython/commit/d2ed4f2254938517ccd7843ce8db810d6fe91ab9 - apply the same change locally if you need to use this urgently by editing C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\Bio\SeqUtils\__init__.py (or reinstalling Biopython from source).

Comment: And if on Python 3, you'll also need https://github.com/biopython/biopython/commit/acf0b9a80718ba9c39f8deb9a23073e98f7fe3e4